# How reconstruct an approximate data set in weka after pca?

Tags: weka, data-mining

I want to reconstruct the data set with reduced dimensionality back to an approximate of the original data set in WEKA. I tried the tranformBackToOriginal in PCA but I got a reduced number of attributes after doing this. How do I know what attribute it really represents of the original data set?

Comment: Maybe PCA only used some of the attributes, i.e. numeric values only. Do you have non-continuous attributes?

Comment: yes i do have non-continuous attributes.

Comment: I did pca again by removing the non numeric attributes, and got 4 attributes (there were 6 in the original data set). Now again if tranform back to original I'm not getting 6 but I'm gettin only 4 attributes. I do not understand why I am not getting 6 attributes in the transformed back to original data set.

Comment: Constant values? Missing values?